# Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 37))

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

how to solve this error?.

I want to print the data of json files but when i debug my code than this error has occured, i was expecting the data of json files as output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
Future<void> readJson() async {
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/jsonFile.json');
final data = await json.decode(response);
print(json.encode(data));
}
```